# How do I create a delta value between several filtered columns in powerbi?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a dataset that involves comparing a Then Year and Base Year value to each other. I am having trouble computing a code to get the delta value of TY from BY. I tried using the filter and calculate functions but that has not worked. I have 3 slicer functions that select columns to print these values but I am having trouble finding a way to subtract the TY from BY after going through the slicer.

I expect a table to list both Base Year and Then Year values, which I did, but I am having trouble trying to create a column that will display a delta value from TY to BY.

Comment: How do you determine base year value? CALCULATE([Measure], Calendar[Year]=1980)?
Do you have a Calendar table? If you want to ignore the filters from the slicers, you have to use ALL() or REMOVEFILTERS() inside your measure to override those and then likely FILTERIO to add some of it back.